# How to pass Multer additional parameter from textfield

Tags: node.js, typescript, upload, multer

I want to make an image upload and name the image after an input field on the same site.

Here is what I have:

Html Text Input:

```
<input type="text" id="uri" formControlName="uri" class="input is-normal"
                    (blur)="logValidationErrors()" aria-describedby="heroaddon" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
              </div>
```

TypeScript:

```
sensorName = "";

  onChange(event) {
    this.sensorName = event.srcElement.value;
    console.log(this.sensorName);
  }

  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/image/upload',
    itemAlias: 'image',
    additionalParameter: {
      sensorUri: this.sensorName
    }
  })
```

and the upload:

```
var express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
var router = express.Router();

const PATH = './public/images/upload/';

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, PATH);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log("storage", req.body);
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

let upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})

router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    console.log("post", req.headers);
    if (!req.file) {
        console.log("No file is available!");
        return res.send({
            success: false
        });

    } else {
        // fs.renameSync(req.file.path, req.file.path.replace(req.file.originalname,
        //     req.body.sensorname + "." + req.file.originalname.split(".")[1]));
        // console.log('File is available!');
        return res.send({
            success: true
        })
    }
});

router.get('/:name', async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/public/images/upload/' + req.params.name + "." + "jpg", { root: './' })
})

// async function getFileExtension(name) {
//     fs.readdir("./public/images/upload/", (err, files) => {
//         files.forEach(file => {
//             console.log(file.split(".")[0], name, file.split(".")[1]);
//             if (file.split(".")[0] == name) {
//                 return file.split(".")[1];
//             }
//         });
//     });
// }


module.exports = router;
```

So the idea is to pass additional parameters to the Multer upload and then just name it after that but the additional `sensorUri`is always an empty string...

Any ideas how to solve this?